# 1024 worker_connections are not enough, reusing connections

Tags: python, django, nginx

2023/11/08 12:59:30 [warn] 1125#1125: 1024 worker_connections are not enough, reusing connections
2023/11/08 12:59:30 [alert] 1125#1125: *2978743 1024 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 197.210.55.148, server: signals.sentinel.vip, request: "GET /api/token/968/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/968/", host: "here is my domin (im hiding it)"

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP;
    client_max_body_size 2G;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /root/signals;
    }

    location / {
if ($http_user_agent ~* (Googlebot|bingbot|Applebot|Slurp|DuckDuckBot|Baiduspider|YandexBot|Sogou|facebot|ia_archiver) ) {
      return 403;
    }
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;

        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
#        proxy_buffers 6 16k;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
}
```

This is my nginx.conf

Any suggestion how i can fix this issue?

Im using django pytho, have 21 workers.

Comment: What about posting at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)? And, in its current state, it will be closed at there also. Research more and ask a specific question there too.